# Links na Webview não funcionam

Tags: android, webview

Mudou alguma coisa na implementação do WebView, WebViewClient para android 7?

Tenho alguns arquivos html em uma subpasta dentro da pasta Assets. O arquivo **lista.html**, que contém outros links que chamam outros arquivos html que estão na mesma pasta, é exibido normalmente mas quando clico nos links para chamar os outros arquivos html não estão sendo exibidos no WebView.

Testei no android 4 e 6 e funciona perfeitamente, no android  7 não funciona.

Segue ocódigo:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.help);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewHelp);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new ActivityHelp.myWebClient());
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/help/lista.html");
}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean  shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Testei o seu código e não obtive nenhum erro. Indique qual o `compileSdkVersion` e `targetSdkVersion`.

Comment: @ramaral, O código não apresenta erro mesmo, como descrito no post, eu tenho uma subpasta dentro do assets no qual estão os arquivos html. O webview carrega o arquivo html **lista.html** normalmente, mas se eu clico em um link contido nesse arquivo para chamar outro arquivo na mesma pasta (**help**) o arquivo não é carregado no webview.

No android 4 e 6 nos quais eu fiz os testes funciona perfeitamente, mas no android 7 simplesmente não carrega.

Comment: Você não dá essa informação na pergunta. Edite-a e coloque-a lá.

Comment: @ramaral, editei a pergunta.

Comment: @ramaral, só para complementar a questão e respondendo suas perguntas, estou utilizando compileSdkVersion 25 e targetSdkVersion 25

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No método `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` em vez de retornar `true` retorne `false`.

`true` indica que vai ser a aplicação a tratar a URL(por exemplo lançar um Intent com o link para que seja visto no Browser nativo) e não a WebView. Assim, para que a WebView apresente a página referente à URL, o método deve retornar `false`.

O *overload* do método `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` com essa assinatura, [`boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)), só foi adicionada na API 24.
O outro, [`boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)), passou a ser considerado obsoleto.

A razão porque funciona nas versões anteriores, é que o *override* daquele *overload*(que só existe a partir do 7) não vai ser chamado, sendo chamada a implementação "base" do outro método, que retorna `false`.
Ou seja, estar lá ou não, retornar `true` ou `false` é o mesmo, ele não é chamado.
O estranho é o Android Studio não dar nenhum *warning/error* em como o método só pode ser usado com `minSdkVersion 24`.

De qualquer forma, a maneira correcta para a implementação, já que quer dar suporte a versões inferiores, será fazer o *override* dos dois métodos.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);

    //fazer alguma coisa aqui

    return false;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public boolean  shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);

    //fazer alguma coisa aqui

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Após alteração sugerida por **ramaral** está funcionando normalmente no android 7. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Ramaral, sinta-se a vontade para descrever um pouco mais sobre o método `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` para que possam entender exatamente o que vem a ocorrer no código do Henqsan . Desde já, tem o meu +1;

Comment: O true é quando você quer negar o comportamento padrão, não? Então dentro da condição imposta em uma suposta `if` você decide customizar a resposta ou criar um protocolo customizado, para todas `else`s seria `false` para seguir com o comportamento padrão. Creio eu, não estou bem certo :)

Comment: @ramaral também não sei porque o true/false se comportava diferente, talvez funcionasse ao "contrário" ou simplesmente para abortar uma requisição você tinha que sobre-escrever os argumentos, de qualquer forma é uma excelente resposta e fui o primeiro a deixar o +1, então já esta garantido :D

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Funcionava com `true` porque o *override* daquele *overload* do método não é chamado em versões inferiores(ele só existe a partir do 7). Ou seja, estar lá ou não, retornar `true` ou `false` é o mesmo. Ele não é chamado no caso de uma versão inferior. O estranho é o Android Studio não dar nenhum *warning/error*.

Comment: @ramaral entendi, realmente é isto, irei efetuar os testes e aproveitar e implementar um protocolo customizado que criei aqui. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Esta resposta é um complemento do assunto da pergunta.

Vamos criar um aplicativo com **webview** no **Android 7 (API 24)** para abrir arquivos **HTML** de **forma local**.

**1)** Primeiro vamos criar os dois arquivos de **HTML** como exemplo:

Os arquivos ficam neste caminho:

```
MyApplication\app\src\main\assets\teste.html
MyApplication\app\src\main\assets\teste2.html
```

**teste.html**

```
<h3>Aaaa</h3>
<a href="teste2.html">Link1</a>
```

**teste2.html**

```
<h3>Bbbb</h3>
<a href="teste.html">Link2</a>
```

**2)** Vamos editar o arquivo de layout **XML** da aplicação (**MainActivity**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.computador1.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**3)** Agora vamos configurar a parte do **java** (**MainActivity**) para ele carregar a webview na **ID** definida no layout.

```
package com.example.computador1.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // permite o uso de javascript
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/teste.html");

    }
}
```

Entenda que a linha:

```
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

É muito importante, pois ela não deixa os links do webview abrirem no navegador padrão do Android. Assim eles sempre abrirão no webview. Agora basta testar a sua aplicação.